# how to implement selectedrow in viewcontroller for subclassed pickerview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uipickerview

I have two UIPickerViews on my storyboard, each subclassed and acting as its own datasource and delegate.  In my subclass I define the number of rows and columns and present the values/labels for each.

I have outlets to both in my main ViewController:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PickerView1 *pv1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PickerView2 *pv2;
```

I would like to use the delegate method

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

to trigger an update of information on the main view.  But the problem is the main ViewController is not the delegate for either (and anyway, coudn’t be for both at the same time), and there are no IBActions associated with UIPickerView that I can see.  The method above will be called in my subclass (which is it's own delegate) and I don't know how to get this action back to my main viewcontroller

So my question is is there any way to get “didSelectRow” in the subclass to trigger an action in my main ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

you could write a protocol, but as there is one in UIKit with the exact method you want it seems to me the path of least resistance is this..

1. add the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol to your UIViewController
2. Implement the didSelectRow there

   //

   ```
    -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

       if (pickerView == self.pv1){

          //respond to PV1..

       }else{

          //respond to PV2..

       }
       }
   ```
3. add a second delegate property to your two pickerView subclasses (in the header so the UIViewController can use the setter..)

   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet id  < UIPickerViewDelegate >  deligoat;
4. hook your viewController up to be deligoat to both pickers, either in IB or in code..
5. pass it on..

   //inside the pickerView subclasses

   -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

   [self.deligoat pickerView:pickerView didSelectRow:row inComponent:component] ;
   }